# Multidimensional Glivenko-Cantelli

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\{X_i\}_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random varibles with continuous density $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$.

From  the proof of the Glivenko–Cantelli theorem we can say that it $n=1$, for any set $E\subset \mathbb R$ such that $E$ has at most $M$ boundary points,

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{E}(X_i)\to \mathbb P(X_1\in E)$$

almost surely and uniformly with respect to $E$, in the sense that

$$\bigg |\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{E}(X_i)-\mathbb P(X_1\in E)\bigg |\le c(M,n)\to 0$$

**Is there an analogus result which holds for $n>1$ exploiting the perimeter of the set $E$?**